# window.location.hash issue in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

We have a javascript function that should "move" a page to a certain position using anchors. This function just does `window.location.href = "#" + hashName`. This works in FF, but not in IE. I tested this code using IE7 under Windows XP. 
I have tried `using window.location.href`, `window.location.hash`, `window.location.replace` and all these ways, but using `document` object.
Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: What do you mean with 'using document object'? You should use `window.location` as suggested in the answers - `document.location` is Gecko-specific!

Comment: I used both of them - and they don't work

Comment: Vladimir, works for me in IE7/XP ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE and most other browsers will scroll to an anchor with anchor.focus(), or to any element with an id with element.scrollIntoView(true)

Answer (score 4):

I justed tested this in IE7 under Vista, maybe the issue only exsists in IE7 under XP? Because this works fine for me in IE7, Chrome and Firefox:

```
 window.location.hash = hashName;
```

If this really doesn't work then we could use scrollIntoView as Kennebec suggests.

```
 function scrollToAnchor(anchorName){
   //set the hash so people can bookmark
   window.location.hash = anchorName;
   //scroll the anchor into view
   document.getElementsByName(anchorName)[0].scrollIntoView(true);
 }
```

Use like this:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>scrollIToAnchor('foo');</script>
 <a name='foo'></a>
 <p>I will be scrolled into view</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing just `location.hash`?

```
window.location.hash = "#" + hashName;
```

Comment: not familiar with this. looks good, though. *goes to test...*

Answer (score 0):

There is also a problem i came across

http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/window-location-hash-difference-in-ff3-and-opera